# Database doesn't write even though no "Fault" is returned

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get the Firebase Database component working with my iOS project, and when my code (included below) executes it will output the "succeeded" message, but the database is not modified. I've also included an "error" I'm receiving in my Xcode Logs.

Thank you for any help!

```js
public IEnumerator GetProfile() {
  Task < DataSnapshot > task = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("users/" + _currentUser.UserId).GetValueAsync();

  while (!task.IsFaulted && !task.IsCanceled && !task.IsCompleted)
    yield
  return null;

  if (task.IsCompleted) {
    //set data
    Debug.Log("has data");
    DataSnapshot snapShot = task.Result;
    if (snapShot.Value == null) {
      Debug.Log("no value");
      Task postNew = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference.Child("users").Child(_currentUser.UserId)
        .SetRawJsonValueAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new User()));

      while (!postNew.IsFaulted && !postNew.IsCanceled && !postNew.IsCompleted)
        yield
      return null;

      if (postNew.IsFaulted) {
        Debug.Log(postNew.Exception.ToString());
      } else
        Debug.Log("suceeded");
    }
  } else {
    Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
    /*_root.Child("users").Child(_currentUser.UserId)
      .SetRawJsonValueAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new User()));*/
  }
}
```

"error"

```html
<Error> [Firebase/Core][I-COR000003] The default Firebase app has not yet been configured. Add `[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) to your application initialization. Read more: ...
```

Comment: Are you calling `FirebaseApp.configure()` in the App Delegate?

Comment: I've tried, but when I do it actually causes more errors; specifically about having a Firebase app already configured.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the JSON string I was sending had a value with "null" so the write was silently failing. (Had another developer help me find it).